# Unambiguously Questionable Numbers

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

The examples below are considered Unambiguously Questionable Numbers:

> 8 to 7 is 8
>   23 to 22 is 5
>   628 to 626 is 2
>   3969 to 3943 is 3
>   7712 to 7701 is 9
>   19824 to 19823 is 5
>   19897 to 19870 is 18
>   32236 to 32235 is 1713
>   32378 to 32377 is 31
>   40808 to 40806 is 5106
>   42939 to 42891 is 18

Explain what is the "to" operator and find the Unambiguously Questionable Number for the equation below (find **X**):

> **X to 44493 is X**

Answer to @humn's question in the comment:

> There are numerical values of *a* and *b* such that:
>  *a > 0* and *b > 0* and *a != b* and the value of *a to b* does not exist.

And

> there are quite a lot of them. For example all possible values of *a* and *b* from 1 to 100 are already presented by the first two equations.

Comment: Is there a secret meaning to the "is" or it is the same as "="?

Comment: @stack reader you could replace the "is" with "=" if this is more readable for you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if the "lateral-thinking" tag fits this question, but I feel it is more accurate than "calculation-puzzle" or "mathematics"

Comment: Very interesting additional hint about what is (not) missing from the examples. I was gearing up to ask that exact question. Also interesting is that the very first example, "8 to 7 is 8," is similar in form to the mystery statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the expression **X to Y is Z**,

> Y is the question number on this site, X is the post number of the accepted answer, and Z is the numerical answer to the question itself. Only questions with numerical answers can be fit to this pattern.

For example,

> in **3969 to 3943 is 3**, 3943 refers to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/whats-the-password-again), 3969 refers to [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/3969/31180), with the numerical answer three.

So

> 44501 to 44493 is 44501, because this answer's post number is 44501, which is both the post number *and* the numerical answer.

Comment: I don't get Z, where does it come from?

Comment: Z is the actual answer to the puzzle, contained in comment Y.

Comment: Could you give a further explanation as to how you reached this conclusion. How is X=44501?

Comment: Awesome, nicely done!  @Sid If you click the "share" link at the bottom of this answer, you'll see that it is post #44501 on this site.

Comment: @djb212 I tidied up the explanation a bit so it was clearer.  Hope you don't mind, and welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: @djb212 Before I accept this answer (I will, don't worry) try to explain two more things: 1. Why the numbers are called Unambiguously Questionable Numbers? 2. Why this is not a correct answer?

Comment: Great puzzle and answer! And just wanted to say I'm flattered that my riddle made it into the list, too. :D

Comment: @oleslaw Are the answers to these additional questions: 1. because there can be only one accepted answer (at a time), which makes it unambiguous, and 2. because this is not yet accepted?

Comment: @Arkku 2. yes, 1. yes, but additionally that the answer must consist of 1 number (more than 1 number in the answer would make it ambiguous). Thank you for explaining these.