# What will be the passcode for entry into this party?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, password

I came across this question in a Mental Ability Test. The question is as follows —

> Anita, a girl, goes to a party. Entry into the party requires a special passcode. In order to know the passcode she listens to the conversation between the guard and two people.
>
> In the first conversation between the guard and the man, the guard says $12$ and the man says $6$ and he is granted entry.
>
> In the next dialogue between the guard and the lady the guard says $6$ and the woman says $3$ and then she is granted entry.
>
> Then Anita thinking she has got the passcode goes to the guard. The guard says $10$ and Anita says $5$ but the guard says "You are wrong!" and denied her entry.
>
> What should Anita have said to gain entry?

I have no idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: I can guarantee that this is a duplicate, but can't find the original...

Comment: @Deusovi I found http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/3943/21503 but that's not a duplicate

Comment: Oh this might be considered a duplicate http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2497/21503

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anita should've said:

> 3

Because

> The responses are the number of letters in each number. 12 = twelve = 6 letters, 6 = six = 3 letters, 10 = ten = 3 letters.

Answer (score 1):

Anita should've said:

> 8

Because

> The passcode is the number between 0 and 8 that must be added to the guard's number to render a result which is divisible by 9.
>  12 + 6 = 18; 6 + 3 = 9; 10 + **8** = 18.

Comment: Well indeed. I can't possibly know that, but I don't think there's any information in the question that rules this out as a possible answer. If this question was really being used in a "mental ability test", I hope it's not on the assumption that there's only one possible correct answer.

Comment: If you'd like another, how about "multiply the number of digits by three and subtract from the original number". Then the answer is 10 - 6 = **4**.

Comment: (+1)Thanks for your answer...your logic is quite correct but in the MCQ exam,the options included 10,20,6,3 as the valid answers...

Comment: I'm glad they at least allowed for several possibilities! Now I'll see if I can work out how 10, 20, and 6 can be obtained :)

Comment: Yeah...please go on..I encourage your positive spirit!!

Comment: Well, trivially, we can construct a quadratic polynomial for any value: $f(n)=\frac14 n^2-4n+18↦f(6)=3, f(10)=3, f(12)=6$; $f(n)=-\frac18n^2+\frac{11}4n-9↦f(10)=6$; $f(n)=-\frac58n^2+\frac{47}4n-45↦f(10)=10$; and $f(n)=-\frac{15}8n^2+\frac{137}4n-135↦f(10)=20$ (thanks, [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+calculator&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22)).  But,  if  you  want  to  disallow  exponents,  how  about $f(n)=3\times⌈\frac{n+1}{10}⌉↦f(10)=6$; $f(n)=\frac74n-\frac{15}2⌈\frac{n}{10}⌉↦f(10)=10$; and $f(n)=\frac{n}2+15\times(n\bmod 3)↦f(10)=20$.